# nextjs redirect url with a // pattern

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am using react+nextjs in a project.  I am having this problem of supporting legacy url pattern of `https://server:port//_/additional/path/params/` to a new url.

Going through the official documentation, I created the following nextjs.config.

```
module.exports = ({
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/product/:path*',
        destination: '/old-urls-handler',
        permanent: true
      },
      {
        source: '/_/:path*',
        destination: '/old-urls-handler',
        permanent: true
      },
      {
        source: '//_/:path*',
        destination: '/old-urls-handler',
        permanent: true
      }
      ]
  },
```

The above configuration works, if the incoming url pattern is
`https://server:port/_/additional/path/params/`  (note: **without the extra slash after the port**).  But if the path contains two slashes, (as in https://server:port**//**_/additional/path/params/)  I am unable to receive the request on the destination url.

Any help on how to resolve the above issue...?

**Update**
I added the below code in _app.js => getInitialProps.  And removed custom configuration from next.config.js.  It works on my localhost, but when deployed to vercel, it fails.

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async function({ Component, ctx }) {
  console.log("Catch all page with ctx: ctx")
  var redirect = false
  let url
  if (ctx.req.url.startsWith('//_')) {
    url = ctx.req.url.slice(3)
    redirect = true
  } else if (ctx.req.url.startsWith('/_')) {
    url = ctx.req.url.slice(2)
    redirect = true
  }  else if (ctx.req.url.startsWith('/product')) {
    url = ctx.req.url
    redirect = true
  }
  if (redirect) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: `/old-urls-handler?src=${url}`
    }) 
    ctx.res.end();
  }
  
  let pageProps = {}
  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
  }
  return { pageProps }
}
```

Comment: How about using regular expression like this. `source: '/+_/:path*'`

Comment: I get an error  
Error parsing `/+_/:path*` https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-route-source
Reason: Unexpected MODIFIER at 1, expected END

  /+_/:path*
   ^